# Hibernate Mapping one to many hbm file

Tags: hibernate, orm, mapping

I am a bit confused about the hibernate mapping.

whether following mapping will establish parent child relationship.:

```
   <many-to-one name="courseId" column="courseid" insert="true" lazy="false">   </many-to-one>
```

or

```
 <many-to-one name="courseId" class="com.xxx.client.vo.CourseMasterVO"  lazy="false" insert="true" cascade="all">
      <column  name="courseId_Id" not-null="false" />
   </many-to-one>
```

Which one is correct one , if both are correct then can i use them interchangeably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use them interchangeably. The `column` element is only to add additional parameters to the column, like `index` or `not-null` constraints. If you only have a `name`, you can put this into the `column` attribute of the `many-to-one` element.

Comments:

Be careful with the lazy attribute on single-ended properties. False is default then (in contrast to lazy on entities and collections). This feature controls property-wise lazy loading which only works when the class containing the property is a proxy.

Be careful with insert. You should really know what you are doing when using this. It's not for regular Hibernate usage, it's more to work around special cases (which should be avoided).

Comment: cleared the doubts and added some valuable point to my knowledge bank.